# Direct product vs direct sum of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the difference between direct sum and direct product between groups $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}_m$?

I that the same? I found in different literature different notation and I'm very confused about that.

Comment: Some authors adhere to the convention that we say direct sum if both groups are abelian, direct product otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

For only finitely terms of $G_i, i\in I$, where $I=1,...n$, the direct product and direct sum is the same $\prod_{i\in I} G_i=\sum_{i\in I} G_i$.

However, if $I$ is a infinite set, $\prod_{i\in I} G_i$ is much bigger than $\sum_{i\in I} G_i$ in the following sense: $\sum_{i\in I} G_i$ consist of element $g=\{g_i\}_{i\in I}$ and $g_i \in G_i$, where $g_i\neq e_i$ for only finitely terms. While  $\prod_{i\in I} G_i$ admits element with infinite nonzero terms.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank You. I was looking Z_2 and Z_3 which are finite so everything makes sense now. :)

Comment: @user222801 You may _accept_ the answer if it completely solves your problem, just beneath the button for voting up or down.